# Paging in java script

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am working in chrome extension, I want to make paging for table which is fill dynamically using sqlite queries.

I am using this tutorial to make the paging and make some modification in init function

http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/

When I want to get the length of the table after filling it, the dom seems to be not ready and the result return as ZERO of table length, here's some of my code..

```
function ViewAllNotes(db){
 var allListItems;   
  var cur = fromDateToString(new Date(),"date");

       db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT NOTE_DESC,NOTE_DATE,NOTE_TIME FROM NOTES where NOTE_DATE = ? order by NOTE_TIME desc ",[cur],function(tx,result){
             alert(result.rows.length);

           for(i=0;i< result.rows.length;i++){
                 tr= "<tr>";
                 tr=tr+ "<td>"+ result.rows.item(i)['NOTE_DESC']+"</td>";
                  tr=tr+ "<td>"+ result.rows.item(i)['NOTE_TIME']+"</td>";
                 tr=tr+ "</tr>";
                allListItems+=tr;

            }


            var tableContent= " <thead><tr><th id='activityHeader'>Activity</th> <th>Time</th></tr></thead>";
            tableContent = tableContent+"<tbody>"+allListItems+"</tbody>";

            $("table#notes").append(tableContent);
                //$('#notes').dataTable();
                },onError);

        }); 

    }
```

**EDIT**
At the begining of the js file I make like this

```
ViewAllNotes(db);
var rows = document.getElementById("notes").rows;
alert("rows "+rows.length);
```

then call the pager class, **but also it alerts with zero ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL calls are aysynchronous.  Your code that tests for length will not have a length available until the SQL finishes and fires the callback.

Comment: please check the question again, I edit it after your answer.

Comment: The first line of ViewAllNotes invocation is asynch.  Treat it like an ajax call.  Anything that follows will not have access to that state until it completes.  There are no guaruntees when it will complete--it depends on the browser, db query, etc.  Your best bet is to use a promise pattern, single-actor model, events, or pub/sub (observer) to tell the remaining code when the SQL is finished.

Comment: @Alaa a proper way to do this is to pass a callback function into that `ViewAllNotes` and then your function calls it.